# ClientContext.Load on data that is already loaded

Tags: client-object-model, sharepoint-addin

I need clarification how does `ClientContext.ExecuteQuery` method works in client context. For example if I use `ClientContext.Load` to load the data that is already initialized - will it make an request again to refresh loaded information or use previously loaded data and make no web request?

Answer (score 0):

It will always query for the data you pass into `Load`. The reason for this is that the data might have changed in the meantime (the data you have loaded as 'cache' might already be stale).

Unless you're loading an absolute crapload of data, and you are indeed loading it in batches (running ExecuteQuery infrequently) then you shouldn't notice much of a dip in user experience.